# How to avoid automatically inserting <p>&nbsp;</p> in CKEditor.?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am setting the input to CKEditor from back-end. When i give an set of paragraph values, it automatically inserting the `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. How can i avoid this insertion of tag.

```
<p>A wolf wants to eat the girl but is afraid to do so in public. He approaches the girl, and she naïvely tells him where she is going. <p>He suggests the girl pick some flowers, which she does. In the meantime, he goes to the grandmother's house and gains entry by pretending to be the girl.</p> He swallows the grandmother whole, and waits for the girl, disguised as the grandmother.</p>
```

After loading this into editor it's changing into :

```
<p>
A wolf wants to eat the girl but is afraid to do so in public. He approaches the girl, and she na&iuml;vely tells him where she is going.</p>
<p>
He suggests the girl pick some flowers, which she does. In the meantime, he goes to the grandmother&#39;s house and gains entry by pretending to be the girl.</p>
<p>
He swallows the grandmother whole, and waits for the girl, disguised as the grandmother.</p>
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
```

I want to avoid that extra `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.

And i have used the below code but no use.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
{
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
        {
            indent : false,
            breakBeforeOpen : false,
            breakAfterOpen : false,
            breakBeforeClose : false,
            breakAfterClose : false
        });
});
```

Can any one help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid! ;)

HTML doesn't allow nesting paragraphs. Try this one and see that everything is fine (no ghost `&nbsp;`):

```
<p>A wolf wants to eat the girl but is afraid to do so in public. He approaches the girl, and she naïvely tells him where she is going.</p>
<p>He suggests the girl pick some flowers, which she does. In the meantime, he goes to the grandmother's house and gains entry by pretending to be the girl.</p> 
<p>He swallows the grandmother whole, and waits for the girl, disguised as the grandmother.</p>
```